# Ability to mark/highlight squares in the PGN viewer

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

I recently found that someone [used pawns to mark key squares](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1525/478). I didn't find it funny to start studying the position to later read *"I marked these other squares with white pawns"*...

But maybe the PGN reader can be improved to allow us to mark squares? maybe even draw arrows, something like [this example](http://www.lutanho.net/pgn/ltpgnboard.html?Init=&ApplyPgnMoveText=1.e4%20d5%3CAd7d5B%3E%3CCe4R%3E%202.d4%20Nc6%3CAd1h5B%3E%3CCf7R%3E%3CBe4R%3E&SetBGColor=EEEEEE&SetBorder=1&eval=AddText%28unescape%28%22%3C%7Ctd%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cdiv%20style=%5C%27height:360px;overflow:auto%5C%27%3E%3CB%3Eheader%20text%3C%7CB%3E%3CBR%3E%3CBR%3E%22%29%20GetHTMLMoveText%280,0,1%29%29), the example was created using `1.e4 d5<Ad7d5B><Ce4R> 2.d4 Nc6<Ad1h5B><Cf7R><Be4R>`.

As you can see, their shortcut is something like (**A** for **a**-rrow, **B** for **b**-order, **C** for background **c**-olor) + (target square) + (first letter of common colors) wrapped in `<...>` just after the move.

Is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: I think this is a pretty good idea.  In my opinion, the syntax for arrows or highlights should be the SCID syntax since it's just a specially formatted comment (ex. `[%draw arrow,c4,f7,red]`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added support for SCID style annotations to the replayer project on github:
http://andrewphoy.github.com/chess-replayer/

The first and last games on that page have arrows.

## SCID annotations

Inside a comment after a move, you can choose to either draw a line or color a square:

For example, the following would show a red square on f7 and green arrows from c4 and g5:

```
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Nf6 
4.Ng5 {[%draw full,f7,red][%draw arrow,c4,f7,green][%draw arrow,g5,f7,green]} *
```

Assuming that the site's version of the replayer gets updated to support these changes, I'll write a more verbose explanation of how to use the media annotations.

As an additional note, if you go to the site, you'll see that you can copy the entire game as well as the position by clicking on the arrow in the upper right of the title bar.

Comment: Thanks for this feature. I've started to use it to good effect, e.g. here: https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/17281/1108. But there is a bug if you flip the board in Chrome.