# Highlight squares

Tags: discussion, feature-request, pgn-viewer

How can I highlight squares under atack and show arrows?

There is [similiar question here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182/ability-to-mark-highlight-squares-in-the-pgn-viewer). Is this feature already supproted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that feature is not supported at the chess.SE site yet. To be clear, that feature *is* built into Andrew's PGN viewer, but that functionality wasn't part of the initial implementation of the viewer at this site. (Similarly, the [ability to include comments/annotations alongside the moves](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/167) is part of the viewer, but not active on the site.) I agree that highlighting and markers would be a nice addition, and I hope we'll be able to get them at some point. My understanding is that just getting the PGN viewer to integrate as seamlessly as the SE staff did was a non-trivial endeavor, so we might not see additional features until the site grows more active. (But that's pure speculation on my part.)